# Python Load csv file to Oracle table

Tags: python, oracle, python-3.x

I'm a python beginner. I'm trying to insert records into a Oracle table from a csv file. 
csv file format : Artist_name, Artist_type, Country . I'm getting below error:

```
Error: File "artist_dim.py", line 42, in <module>
    cur.execute(sqlquery)
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00917: missing comma


    import cx_Oracle as cx
    import csv
    import sys

    ##### Step 1 : Connect to Oracle Database#########
    conn_str=u'hr/hr@localhost:1521/PDBORCL'
    conn= cx.connect(conn_str)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    #######################################
    #### Step 2: FETCH LATEST ROW ID FROM ARTIST_DIM###
    query="SELECT nvl(max(row_id)+1,1) from artist_dim"
    cur.execute(query)
    rownum=cur.fetchone()
    x=rownum[0] 

    with open('D:\python\Artist.csv') as f:
        reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            sqlquery="INSERT INTO ARTIST_DIM VALUES (%d,%s,%s,%s)" %(x,row['Artist_name'],row['Artist_type'],row['Country'])
                    cur.execute(sqlquery)
            x=x+1

    conn.commit()
```

When I try to read the file it is working correctly.

```
    ##### Just to Read CSV File############################
    with open('D:\python\Artist.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            a="row_id %d Artist : %s type : %s  Country : %s " %(x,row['Artist_name'],row['Artist_type'],row['Country'])
            print(a)
            x=x+1
    print(row['Artist_name'],",",row['Artist_type'],",",row['Country'])  

Also, when I try to insert using hard coded values it is working

    sqlquery1="INSERT INTO ARTIST_DIM VALUES (%d,'Bob','Bob','Bob')" %x
    cur.execute(sqlquery1)
```

Comment: Can you include the output from the print statements that are working?

Comment: I have checked the table Artist_dim , records are inserted :
 - 18, Bob ,Bob ,Bob

Comment: There is a new Oracle example of loading from a CSV file at https://github.com/oracle/python-oracledb/blob/main/samples/load_csv.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around the values:

```
sqlquery="INSERT INTO ARTIST_DIM VALUES (%d,'%s','%s','%s')" %(x,row['Artist_name'],row['Artist_type'],row['Country'])
```

Without the quotes it translates to:

```
sqlquery="INSERT INTO ARTIST_DIM VALUES (1, Bob, Bob, Bob)"
```

Comment: Ok.. Is that the tick mark? I'm very new to this forum.

Comment: That did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here's the most efficient way i could do :

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import time

t0_startpoint= time.perf_counter()
con = cx_Oracle.connect('INTEGRATION_USER/Sdx123@orcl')

print("Connected to Oracle")

reader = csv.reader(open("C:\\Users\\FIRAT\\Desktop\\export\\KLINES_1m.csv", "r"))
next(reader) # assumption is your db_table has header
columns = []
for line in reader:
    columns.append(line)

cur = con.cursor()

x=0



for line in columns:  
    insrt_stmt = "insert into INTEGRATION_USER.Klines_1m (opentime,open,high,low,close,volume,closetime,symbol) values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8)"
    cur.execute(insrt_stmt, line)
    x=x+1
    if x%10000==0:
        con.commit()




cur.close()
con.commit()
print("completed")
t1_startpoint = time.perf_counter() - t0_startpoint                    
print("total execution for 1 cycle: ", t1_startpoint) # CPU seconds elapsed (floating point)
```

Comment: Using `executeMany()` to insert a whole batch of records is a LOT faster than using `execute()` in a loop.  The cx_Oracle documentation has an example at the end of the section on [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Comment: @ChristopherJones could you  please give me an example code ? 
 somehow failed to make it work...
 Thank you

Comment: You'll need to provide a sample data file and also the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @ChristopherJones I couldnt reply here, so I added another comment.

Comment: I see the CREATE statement but not a CSV file. The INSERTs are not relevant to your question about reading a CSV file.  (Pro tip: edit your original question and add all the request info to that, not to a new comment)

Answer (score 0):

@ChristopherJones I hope you are okay with the oracle dialect :

```
`create table INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M
(
  opentime  VARCHAR2(30),
  open      NUMBER,
  high      NUMBER,
  low       NUMBER,
  close     NUMBER,
  volume    NUMBER,
  closetime VARCHAR2(30),
  symbol    VARCHAR2(30)
)



insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:23:00.0000000', 0.295, 0.295, 0.2945, 0.2946, 9223, '2021-08-09 03:23:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:24:00.0000000', 0.2949, 0.2949, 0.2944, 0.2944, 7338, '2021-08-09 03:24:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:25:00.0000000', 0.2944, 0.2951, 0.2944, 0.2951, 15191, '2021-08-09 03:25:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:26:00.0000000', 0.2951, 0.2955, 0.2951, 0.2955, 5300, '2021-08-09 03:26:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:27:00.0000000', 0.2955, 0.2955, 0.2948, 0.2948, 43799, '2021-08-09 03:27:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:28:00.0000000', 0.2947, 0.2947, 0.2945, 0.2945, 20376, '2021-08-09 03:28:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:29:00.0000000', 0.2945, 0.2948, 0.2945, 0.2946, 21922, '2021-08-09 03:29:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:30:00.0000000', 0.2946, 0.2954, 0.2946, 0.2954, 28858, '2021-08-09 03:30:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:31:00.0000000', 0.2955, 0.2955, 0.2954, 0.2954, 29103, '2021-08-09 03:31:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:32:00.0000000', 0.2954, 0.2954, 0.2951, 0.2953, 19573, '2021-08-09 03:32:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:33:00.0000000', 0.2953, 0.2958, 0.2953, 0.2958, 22068, '2021-08-09 03:33:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:34:00.0000000', 0.2958, 0.2959, 0.2955, 0.2958, 9945, '2021-08-09 03:34:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:35:00.0000000', 0.2958, 0.2959, 0.2954, 0.2956, 44649, '2021-08-09 03:35:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:36:00.0000000', 0.2957, 0.2957, 0.2953, 0.2953, 47028, '2021-08-09 03:36:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:37:00.0000000', 0.2953, 0.2967, 0.2951, 0.2967, 104472, '2021-08-09 03:37:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:38:00.0000000', 0.2966, 0.2972, 0.2966, 0.2969, 26574, '2021-08-09 03:38:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:39:00.0000000', 0.2971, 0.2972, 0.2969, 0.2971, 7951, '2021-08-09 03:39:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:40:00.0000000', 0.2969, 0.297, 0.2952, 0.297, 121166, '2021-08-09 03:40:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:41:00.0000000', 0.2971, 0.2971, 0.296, 0.2962, 83317, '2021-08-09 03:41:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:42:00.0000000', 0.2962, 0.2969, 0.2962, 0.2968, 16374, '2021-08-09 03:42:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:43:00.0000000', 0.2969, 0.2972, 0.2968, 0.2972, 7285, '2021-08-09 03:43:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:44:00.0000000', 0.2971, 0.2977, 0.297, 0.2974, 34866, '2021-08-09 03:44:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:45:00.0000000', 0.2974, 0.2982, 0.2974, 0.298, 64747, '2021-08-09 03:45:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:46:00.0000000', 0.2979, 0.2979, 0.2971, 0.2974, 8771, '2021-08-09 03:46:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:47:00.0000000', 0.2975, 0.2978, 0.2975, 0.2976, 6785, '2021-08-09 03:47:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:48:00.0000000', 0.2977, 0.298, 0.2974, 0.2978, 11946, '2021-08-09 03:48:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:49:00.0000000', 0.2978, 0.2978, 0.2968, 0.2972, 26987, '2021-08-09 03:49:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:50:00.0000000', 0.2972, 0.2977, 0.2969, 0.2977, 20960, '2021-08-09 03:50:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:51:00.0000000', 0.2976, 0.2979, 0.2976, 0.2978, 57752, '2021-08-09 03:51:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:52:00.0000000', 0.2977, 0.2981, 0.2977, 0.2981, 7339, '2021-08-09 03:52:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:53:00.0000000', 0.2978, 0.2978, 0.2977, 0.2977, 2631, '2021-08-09 03:53:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:54:00.0000000', 0.2976, 0.2977, 0.2975, 0.2975, 4016, '2021-08-09 03:54:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:55:00.0000000', 0.2975, 0.2975, 0.2972, 0.2974, 13992, '2021-08-09 03:55:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:56:00.0000000', 0.2974, 0.2977, 0.2973, 0.2976, 24674, '2021-08-09 03:56:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:57:00.0000000', 0.2978, 0.2978, 0.2974, 0.2974, 6361, '2021-08-09 03:57:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:58:00.0000000', 0.2975, 0.2976, 0.2969, 0.2969, 30812, '2021-08-09 03:58:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 03:59:00.0000000', 0.2968, 0.2971, 0.2963, 0.2971, 31434, '2021-08-09 03:59:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:00:00.0000000', 0.2972, 0.2975, 0.2964, 0.2973, 37315, '2021-08-09 04:00:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:01:00.0000000', 0.2973, 0.2977, 0.2969, 0.2977, 35310, '2021-08-09 04:01:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:02:00.0000000', 0.2977, 0.2978, 0.2968, 0.297, 18896, '2021-08-09 04:02:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:03:00.0000000', 0.297, 0.297, 0.2968, 0.2968, 7500, '2021-08-09 04:03:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:04:00.0000000', 0.2969, 0.2969, 0.2963, 0.2963, 18541, '2021-08-09 04:04:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:05:00.0000000', 0.2964, 0.2964, 0.2958, 0.2958, 40606, '2021-08-09 04:05:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:06:00.0000000', 0.296, 0.2961, 0.2953, 0.2954, 13088, '2021-08-09 04:06:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:07:00.0000000', 0.2954, 0.2957, 0.2953, 0.2954, 25478, '2021-08-09 04:07:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:08:00.0000000', 0.2954, 0.2955, 0.2954, 0.2955, 3576, '2021-08-09 04:08:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:09:00.0000000', 0.2953, 0.2953, 0.2951, 0.2953, 8119, '2021-08-09 04:09:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:10:00.0000000', 0.2953, 0.2955, 0.2953, 0.2954, 10709, '2021-08-09 04:10:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:11:00.0000000', 0.2952, 0.2952, 0.295, 0.295, 7486, '2021-08-09 04:11:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:12:00.0000000', 0.295, 0.2951, 0.2948, 0.2948, 7333, '2021-08-09 04:12:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:13:00.0000000', 0.2947, 0.295, 0.2946, 0.2949, 23738, '2021-08-09 04:13:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:14:00.0000000', 0.2949, 0.2949, 0.2949, 0.2949, 4800, '2021-08-09 04:14:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:15:00.0000000', 0.2949, 0.296, 0.2949, 0.2959, 13685, '2021-08-09 04:15:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:16:00.0000000', 0.2957, 0.2958, 0.2945, 0.2945, 3113, '2021-08-09 04:16:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:17:00.0000000', 0.2945, 0.2949, 0.2945, 0.2946, 16044, '2021-08-09 04:17:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:18:00.0000000', 0.2948, 0.2954, 0.2946, 0.2954, 27647, '2021-08-09 04:18:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:19:00.0000000', 0.2951, 0.2951, 0.2943, 0.2945, 29772, '2021-08-09 04:19:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:20:00.0000000', 0.2943, 0.2945, 0.2933, 0.2935, 36090, '2021-08-09 04:20:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:21:00.0000000', 0.2933, 0.294, 0.2933, 0.294, 8233, '2021-08-09 04:21:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:22:00.0000000', 0.2941, 0.2944, 0.2941, 0.2941, 4930, '2021-08-09 04:22:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:23:00.0000000', 0.294, 0.294, 0.2935, 0.2939, 6886, '2021-08-09 04:23:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:24:00.0000000', 0.2939, 0.2943, 0.2939, 0.2943, 25830, '2021-08-09 04:24:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:25:00.0000000', 0.2943, 0.2943, 0.2937, 0.2939, 25331, '2021-08-09 04:25:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:26:00.0000000', 0.2939, 0.2951, 0.2939, 0.2951, 28500, '2021-08-09 04:26:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:27:00.0000000', 0.2949, 0.2949, 0.2946, 0.2948, 6966, '2021-08-09 04:27:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:28:00.0000000', 0.2947, 0.2952, 0.2947, 0.2951, 15928, '2021-08-09 04:28:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:29:00.0000000', 0.2951, 0.2951, 0.2948, 0.2949, 9243, '2021-08-09 04:29:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:30:00.0000000', 0.2949, 0.2954, 0.2949, 0.2952, 12580, '2021-08-09 04:30:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:31:00.0000000', 0.2955, 0.297, 0.2954, 0.297, 61150, '2021-08-09 04:31:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:32:00.0000000', 0.2971, 0.2972, 0.2963, 0.2967, 53937, '2021-08-09 04:32:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:33:00.0000000', 0.2967, 0.2982, 0.2967, 0.297, 101045, '2021-08-09 04:33:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:34:00.0000000', 0.297, 0.2972, 0.2967, 0.2972, 22941, '2021-08-09 04:34:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:35:00.0000000', 0.2976, 0.2979, 0.2972, 0.2972, 9181, '2021-08-09 04:35:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:36:00.0000000', 0.2969, 0.2978, 0.2969, 0.2974, 12857, '2021-08-09 04:36:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:37:00.0000000', 0.2976, 0.2976, 0.2968, 0.2968, 48609, '2021-08-09 04:37:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:38:00.0000000', 0.297, 0.297, 0.2956, 0.2968, 38441, '2021-08-09 04:38:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:39:00.0000000', 0.2968, 0.2969, 0.2962, 0.2968, 42079, '2021-08-09 04:39:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:40:00.0000000', 0.2968, 0.2968, 0.2964, 0.2965, 3972, '2021-08-09 04:40:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:41:00.0000000', 0.2966, 0.2966, 0.2963, 0.2966, 22720, '2021-08-09 04:41:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:42:00.0000000', 0.2967, 0.2973, 0.2963, 0.2973, 12215, '2021-08-09 04:42:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:43:00.0000000', 0.2973, 0.2973, 0.2967, 0.2967, 5492, '2021-08-09 04:43:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:44:00.0000000', 0.2967, 0.2975, 0.2967, 0.2975, 13214, '2021-08-09 04:44:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:45:00.0000000', 0.2975, 0.2975, 0.2965, 0.2968, 73966, '2021-08-09 04:45:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:46:00.0000000', 0.2968, 0.2971, 0.2966, 0.2967, 28161, '2021-08-09 04:46:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:47:00.0000000', 0.2968, 0.2968, 0.2964, 0.2966, 4607, '2021-08-09 04:47:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:48:00.0000000', 0.2966, 0.2969, 0.2966, 0.2967, 9571, '2021-08-09 04:48:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:49:00.0000000', 0.2967, 0.2971, 0.2966, 0.2966, 5872, '2021-08-09 04:49:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:50:00.0000000', 0.2966, 0.2966, 0.2963, 0.2963, 7934, '2021-08-09 04:50:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:51:00.0000000', 0.2963, 0.2963, 0.2958, 0.2961, 38942, '2021-08-09 04:51:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:52:00.0000000', 0.2961, 0.2963, 0.2957, 0.2963, 9307, '2021-08-09 04:52:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:53:00.0000000', 0.2962, 0.2962, 0.2955, 0.2955, 15507, '2021-08-09 04:53:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:54:00.0000000', 0.2955, 0.296, 0.2954, 0.296, 10974, '2021-08-09 04:54:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:55:00.0000000', 0.2958, 0.2962, 0.2958, 0.2962, 1387, '2021-08-09 04:55:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:56:00.0000000', 0.2962, 0.2962, 0.2961, 0.2961, 4898, '2021-08-09 04:56:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:57:00.0000000', 0.2961, 0.2961, 0.2958, 0.2961, 11189, '2021-08-09 04:57:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:58:00.0000000', 0.2961, 0.2966, 0.2961, 0.2966, 3273, '2021-08-09 04:58:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 04:59:00.0000000', 0.2965, 0.297, 0.2961, 0.2968, 61399, '2021-08-09 04:59:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 05:00:00.0000000', 0.2966, 0.2982, 0.2966, 0.2972, 49434, '2021-08-09 05:00:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 05:01:00.0000000', 0.2971, 0.2974, 0.2966, 0.2968, 10354, '2021-08-09 05:01:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');

insert into INTEGRATION_USER.KLINES_1M (OPENTIME, OPEN, HIGH, LOW, CLOSE, VOLUME, CLOSETIME, SYMBOL)
values ('2021-08-09 05:02:00.0000000', 0.2968, 0.2971, 0.2968, 0.2971, 25002, '2021-08-09 05:02:59.9990000', 'KEEPUSDT');  `
```